# Save outputs from a function in a csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, export-to-csv

So I have created a function which takes in input from the user and then displays the required output.

The function is: `def getname(name, place)`

Then the other code follows. In the end the user is asked name and place. The function searches the dataframe which I have imported and displays the result as the info of that name.

I would like these outputs to be exported to a csv file. Not really sure of how to begin my code in this case.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Pandas is the best solution for this

Comment: and what did you try sofar ?

Answer (score 0):

Basic code to write to a csv is

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: I have changed it.  I copied the python2 example! oops!